# how do I combine 2 files

Tags: python, bash, perl

Unfortunately, I found nothing useful or a clue how I should solve it.

I want to save all combinations between both files in one file

first.txt

```
Black
Blue
Brown
Orange
Red
```

two.txt

```
one
two
three
four
```

I want in the output file this:

```
 Black:one
 Black:two
 Black:three
 Black:four
 Blue:one
 Blue:two
 Blue:three
 Blue:four
 Brown:one
 Brown:two
 Brown:three
 Brown:four
 Orange:one
 Orange:two
 Orange:three
 Orange
 Red:one
 Red:two
 Red:three
 Red:four
```

Unfortunately, I found nothing useful or a clue how I should solve it.

I hope you can help me, it should run under debian

Regards

Comment: You can use `join` for this: https://linux.die.net/man/1/join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
f=open("first.txt")
s=open("second.txt")

for i in f:
    for j in s:
        print(i+":"+j)
    s.seek(0)
```

in python..

try now:

```
f=open("first.txt")
s=open("second.txt")

for i in f:
    for j in s:
        print(i.replace("\n","")+":"+j.replace("\n",""))
    s.seek(0)
```

for saving in text format:

```
f=open("first.txt")
s=open("second.txt")
k=open("third.txt",'w')

for i in f:
    for j in s:
        k.write(i.replace("\n","")+":"+j.replace("\n",""))
        k.write("\n")
    s.seek(0)

k.close()
```

Comment: hi Jainil Patel, output is Black
:one

Black
:two .... etc...

Comment: is it now working fine?

Comment: that is much better, it would fit, can you tell me that it will be saved to a file?

Comment: yeah sure.......

Comment: nice, working perfekt, big thx Jainil Patel

Answer (score 2):

With two while loops:

```
while read -r first; do while read -r second; do echo "$first:$second"; done <second.txt; done <first.txt
```

Or with indent:

```
while read -r first; do 
  while read -r second; do
    echo "$first:$second"
  done <second.txt
done <first.txt
```

Output:

```
Black:one
Black:two
Black:three
Black:four
Blue:one
Blue:two
Blue:three
Blue:four
Brown:one
Brown:two
Brown:three
Brown:four
Orange:one
Orange:two
Orange:three
Orange:four
Red:one
Red:two
Red:three
Red:four
```

---

See: `man bash`

Comment: output from first is, :onek
:twok
:three
:one

Comment: I suggest first: `dos2unix first.txt`

Answer (score 2):

Simplest is with **GNU Parallel** (which is a Perl script):

```
parallel echo {1}:{2} :::: first.txt :::: two.txt
```

If you want the output kept in order, use:

```
parallel -k ...
```

If you want the output in `result.txt`:

```
parallel ... > result.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for first in $(cat first.txt)
do 
    for two in $(cat two.txt)
    do 
        echo "$first:$two"
    done
done
```

Output:

```
Black:one
Black:two
Black:three
Black:four
Blue:one
Blue:two
Blue:three
Blue:four
Brown:one
Brown:two
Brown:three
Brown:four
Orange:one
Orange:two
Orange:three
Orange:four
Red:one
Red:two
Red:three
Red:four
```